# convert wrapped array[long] into vector in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, vector

I have 2 column in data-frame label(1,2,3,4) and Signal 
label is Integer type and Signal is 
wrapped array 
(Signal: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true))

```
signal_list :one wrapped array contain 9k elements (sample data) 

-116, -123, -129, -133, -136, -137, -139, -140, -140, -141, -141, -142, -144, -145, -146, -146, -146, -146, -146, -144, -142, -139, -134, -130, -126, -123, -121, -119, -118, -116, -115, -113, -112, -110, -108, -106, -104, -101, -99, -97, -95, -92, -91, -88, -86, -84, -81, -78, -74, -70, -67, -64, -63, -62, -63, -65, -68, -70, -73, -76, -78, -80, -82, -84, -86, -88, -91, -93, -94, -95, -96, -97, -97, -96, -95, -94, -93, -92, -92, -93, -93, -93, -93, -92, -92, -91, -91, -90, -90, -89, -89, -89, -90, -90, -91, -91, -88, -86, -83, -82, -80, -78, -76, -73, -72, -70, -69, -69, -68, -67, -67, -67, -67, -67, -67, -67, -66, -65, -64, -63, -62, -61, -60, -60, -59, -57, -56, -54, -52, -47, -32, -20, -7, 5, 20, 29, 35, 40, 45, 47, 47, 44, 39, 32, 24, 17, 8, -1, -9


I want to convert this both into the vector.
i have used following 
val convertUDF = udf((array : Seq[Long]) => {
  Vector(array.toArray)
})

it gives wrapped array inside the vector
 [WrappedArray(-116, -123, -129, -133, -136, -137, -139, -140, -140)]

i want the only element in the vector and I want to ask one more thing will vector handle 9k elements.?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
scala> val df = spark.range(10)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala> df.show
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  5|
|  6|
|  7|
|  8|
|  9|
+---+

scala> val list = df.agg(collect_list("id").as("id"))
list: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: array<bigint>]

scala> list.show(false)
+------------------------------+
|id                            |
+------------------------------+
|[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]|
+------------------------------+

scala> val convertUDF = udf((array : Seq[Long]) => {
     | array.toVector }
     | )
convertUDF: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,ArrayType(LongType,false),Some(List(ArrayType(LongType,false))))

scala> list.select(convertUDF(col("id")).as("vector")).show
+--------------------+
|              vector|
+--------------------+
|[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...|
+--------------------+


scala> list.select(convertUDF(col("id")).as("vector")).printSchema
root
 |-- vector: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = false)
```

Comment: thank you, I know it is possible for ID column but in what should I do for signal_list col which contains wrapped array with 9k elements.

Comment: No, It's not working because of wrapped array I think [Label: int, vector: array<bigint>]

Answer (score 0):

```
val convertUDF = udf((array : Seq[Long]) => {
  Vectors.dense(array.toArray.map(_.toDouble))
})
```

This worked for me